# XXHash as a Mysql User Defined Function

Tags: mysql, hash

We store representations of millions of chemical compounds as BLOBs in a MySQL database. We also keep hashes of these BLOBs when we need to query among these compounds and comparing these hashes in the queries.

Since we found out that standard hash functions(such as CRC) provided by MySQL library collides frequently for our use-case, we used a custom hash function specific to our data, wrapped it as a MySQL plugin and created a [User Defined Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html#udf-calling) with this plugin as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION customhash RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'customhash.so'
```

Unfortunately, we need to move our MySQL installation to another managed data centre and because of the security reasons & data centre policy, we are not allowed to customize MySQL by adding plugins.

We've recently heard about the **XXHash** library, we made a few tests on it and we found out it has great performance and it doesn't generate collisions in our data. Also, it turns out it has already been used by [MySQL standard distribution](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/extra/lz4/xxhash.c) internally.

I wonder if it is possible to configure MySQL server to call **XXH64_digest** function in our MySQL routines without compiling it as a plugin.

Comment: if you have the dode, you can rebuild i in mysql code.

Comment: MySQL has an MD5 funftion too

Comment: MD5 is not enough and collides often in our case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked **MySQL** source code and built-in functions and I could not find any way to run **XXHash** in **MySQL** routines. It seems **XXHash** is used by **MySQL** internally and it is not user-visible.

In order to run **XXHash** in **MySQL** routines, I have developed a plugin in case anyone needs to use **XXHash** algorithm in **MySQL** server.

This plug in can be found here: [Github repository for **xxhash_mysql_plugin**](https://github.com/tkiziloren/xxhash_mysql_plug_in).

After installing plug in you can run the xxhash function in your select statements as below:

[image]

Comment: It seems great. I'm trying to compile for MariaDB to use it for checksums although having a really hard time. Tried with limysqldev and also with libmariadb-dev-compat but no luck.
Have you ever compiled to use on MariaDB ? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry but I haven't compiled it to use on MariaDB. But it should have the same plug-in architecture as my MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I built docker image for that

[image]

Just see https://hub.docker.com/r/vuongtlt13/mysql for details

Comment: Building a docker image is great. However, adding a bit more detail to your answer explaining how to do it would be appreciated as it helps readers understand what exactly your custom function does.

Comment: Ok, i will link github for that